# Where can I find reliable information on C++11, std new features and Tr1?

Tags: c++, c++11, std, tr1

I am trying to make the most of the new standart. However, I am having dificult in find solid information about C++11 like good explanations on **the new keywords and syntax**.

Another problem has been to find information about s**ome new features on the std**. With exception of the wikipedia and the C++ Annotations, I cannot find any other information.

The same is true for the **TR1.**

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Find the latest standard draft and try it... or buy the standard copy.

Comment: AFAIK, TR1 should be headed towards irrelevance. Everything in TR1 has either been incorporated into C++11, or it hasn't. The things that have, you should be switching to the `std::` version as soon as your compiler supports it. The things that haven't, are in effect abandoned (for now, there could yet be a TR2) so move away from them. TR1 is only interesting now in that it's a little bit more portable than an extension that's purely the invention of one compiler/library vendor. It's no longer a view of what the future might look like, as it originally was.

Comment: @Griwes: That's not really a good explanation of new keywords and syntax.

Comment: Not complete yet, but a lot of work is being put into this site: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp Special thanks to fellow Stack Overflower @Cubbi

Comment: wikipedia has been the most useful for me, you probably could take that and the full spec and get the rest of the depth you believe you are missing.

Comment: @UncleBens: that's why it isn't answer, but comment...

Comment: No idea if this will work for you: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/10?m=1628061#1628061

Comment: Stroustrup has written a fairly comprehensive overview of the new C++11 features: http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html

Comment: See here:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest working draft of C++11 standard (which is N3291 at this time) is available for download [here](http://www.open-std.org/Jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/).

Edit: It seems that N3291 is not available for public download, you can download the previous version (N3242) instead.

Comment: They removed n3291 (FDIS) a few days after its publication, my bet is that there was no (or little) change in the Standard.

Answer (score 1):

Start with the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) page.

If you are using GCC then check their [status](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html) page as well. On the GCC status page you can also find links to many of the proposals for the features. This does not have the new standard library of course.